# Function (algorithm) for obtaining random number(s) from dice

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, random

I'm afraid I don't speak maths very well. I hope this question is sufficiently comprehensible and mathematical.

Suppose I have a perfect D$x$ (i.e. $x$-sided) die, and a pen and paper, and with these I wish to obtain a random integer between 1 and $n$ such that every possible result $r$ is equally likely, where $x≥2$, $n>1$, and $1≤r≤n$.

**Is there a known algorithm/procedure/function/protocol that provides such output from such input? If so, what is it called, and how does it work?**

(Presumably, the protocol will involve rolling the die more than once if $n>x$.)

Comment: search term for you, arithmetic encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many such algorithms, with different efficiencies. There is a very simple algorithm which I will demonstrate with two examples.

First, consider the case where you want to use a six sided dice to generate a random number between 1 and 100.

Roll the dice 3 times. There are 216 (6 x 6 x 6) possible results. If you roll 1,1,1 the random number is 1. If it is 1,1,2 the random number is 2, ... 1,1,6 gives the random number 6,  1,2,1 is 7 ... 1,2,6 is 12 ... 3,3,1 is 100. If it is higher than 3,3,1 then discard the answer and throw the dice another 3 times.

This is not particularly efficient, because you will have to roll the dice on average about 6 times (216/100 * 3) to produce one random number. But it is easy to generate.

Or if your dice is 2 sided (like a coin), and you want a number between 1 and 1,000, flip it 10 times. Considered as a binary number where Heads = 1 and Tails  = 0 this will give you a random number between 0 and 1023. If you only want numbers between 1 and 1,000 inclusive, then if your ten throws produces 0 or a number between 1001 and 1023 then start again. (this actually is reasonably efficient, because you will only have to repeat the experiment for a 24/1024 possible sequences).

The same idea can be used for any number of sides and any possible range of random numbers.